# d3 geo transform and scale

Tags: d3.js, geo, geojson

Im trying to combine http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541 using a map of the districts in Paris.

My implementation is here:

http://bl.ocks.org/dvreed77/ad8c1c6cd29d3972eb6c

The problem is that the way its currently implemented, the zoom in feature doesn't quite zoom in on the center, but gets pretty close.  The only difference that I can tell between my code and Mike Bostock's code is the "translate" that is commented out within the click function.  If I uncomment this, the map will fly off the screen.  I can't wrap my head around how this translate and scale works and have been stuck trying to get this working.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently translating the center of the selected object to the upper left corner of the SVG. The additional translation you've commented out took care of translating it to the center of the screen, but doesn't work for you because you're using a different translation for your projection.

To fix, simply add the translation by half the width and height manually:

```
var transform = 
  "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")"  +
  "scale(" + .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height) + ")"
  +
  "translate(" + -(b[1][0] + b[0][0]) / 2 + "," + -(b[1][1] + b[0][1]) / 2 + ")";
```

Complete example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/f7340645d4cda3ff6ac5).